# Throw Exception for Invalid JSONPath while parsing json for specific object key

Tags: json, exception, jsonpath, checked-exceptions, unchecked-exception

I am trying to read a list from a specific object key cars

Input is `jsonString`:

```
{
  "id": 600000,
  "name": "Ayman",
  "cars": [
    {
      "manufacturer": "Volvo",
      "economy" : 65,
      "price" : 100000
    }
}
```

Desired output is:

```
"cars": [
  {
    "manufacturer": "Volvo",
    "economy" : 65,
    "price" : 100000
  }
```

Here is my code:

```
objectKey=$.cars[*]
JsonPath.parse(jsonString).read(objectKey);
```

I want to throw an exception if my objectKey is not present. 
Does JsonPath provide a mechanism to throw exception when key is not present?